# Error al iniciar sesión con Google en FLUTTER

Tags: android, flutter

El problema es el siguiente :

Cuando quiero ingresar por primera vez o luego de cerrar sesión con google la app abre el recuadro para elegir la cuenta y al hacer click la app se cierra dejando el siguiente error en el log.

```
I/ple.salepartid(  538): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/content/ModernAsyncTask;
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at android.support.v4.content.Loader com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity$zzc.onCreateLoader(int, android.os.Bundle) ((null):2)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createLoader(int, android.os.Bundle, android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks) (LoaderManager.java:539)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(int, android.os.Bundle, android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks) (LoaderManager.java:548)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at android.support.v4.content.Loader android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(int, android.os.Bundle, android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks) (LoaderManager.java:603)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.zzn() ((null):80)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent) ((null):68)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(java.lang.String, int, int, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (Activity.java:7454)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, java.util.List, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:4353)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(android.os.IBinder, java.util.List, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:4402)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(android.app.ClientTransactionHandler, android.os.IBinder, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions) (ActivityResultItem.java:49)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1808)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:193)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6669)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:495)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/ple.salepartid(  538): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.salepartido-NEXqk2QoE2Eubmyj-I4dBw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.salepartido-NEXqk2QoE2Eubmyj-I4dBw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.salepartido-NEXqk2QoE2Eubmyj-I4dBw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at android.support.v4.content.Loader com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity$zzc.onCreateLoader(int, android.os.Bundle) ((null):2)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createLoader(int, android.os.Bundle, android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks) (LoaderManager.java:539)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(int, android.os.Bundle, android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks) (LoaderManager.java:548)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at android.support.v4.content.Loader android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(int, android.os.Bundle, android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks) (LoaderManager.java:603)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.zzn() ((null):80)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity.onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent) ((null):68)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(java.lang.String, int, int, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (Activity.java:7454)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, java.util.List, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:4353)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(android.os.IBinder, java.util.List, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:4402)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(android.app.ClientTransactionHandler, android.os.IBinder, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions) (ActivityResultItem.java:49)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1808)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:193)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6669)
I/ple.salepartid(  538):   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
Lost connection to device.
```

Función de logueo:

```
 void signInWithGoogle() async {
// Attempt to get the currently authenticated user
GoogleSignInAccount currentUser = _googleSignIn.currentUser;
if (currentUser == null) {
  // Force the user to interactively sign in
  currentUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
}
final GoogleSignInAuthentication auth =
await currentUser.authentication.catchError((e) {
  print('error');
});
// Authenticate with firebase
final FirebaseUser user = await _auth
    .signInWithGoogle(
  idToken: auth.idToken,
  accessToken: auth.accessToken,
)
    .catchError((e) {
  print('error');
});
if (user != null) {
  print('logueado con google');

}
assert(user != null);
assert(!user.isAnonymous);
}
```

Función que al detectar una cuenta te envia a la pagina de inicio:

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount account) {
  setState(() {
    _currentUser = account;
    print('loged google user');
    Home();
  });
});
}
```

Pareciera ser un error en las tareas de Async pero no se cual puede ser , trato de agregar prints o hacer un debug pero no logro encontrar el problema.

Cabe aclarar que despues de que se cierra la app , si vuelvo a abrir la app y preciono el boton de logueo otra vez , la app no muestra la opcion de elegir el usuario de google e ingresa sin problemas.

No puedo agregar imagenes porque no tengo ningun error que se muestre visualmente.

Comment: donde inicializas la variable _googleSignIn ?

Comment: Al comienzo de la clase dentro de lo que seria el LoginPage reconoces el error ModernAsyncTask dentro del log ??

Comment: estas probando en emulador o dispositivo real?

Comment: Dispositivo real y en emulador , en ambos falla

Comment: ya tienes configurado tu app en firebase? pusiste le código SHA-1 generado en base al package y key que usas?

Comment: Sisi está todo porque lo vengo utilizando en una compu y nunca cambié de pc , si no lo tuviera directamente no haría nada . Creo que me pasó desde que actualicé el plugin de flutter a la última versión , aunque no te lo puedo asegurar .

Comment: conseguiste arreglarlo @GonzaG ?

Comment: @PabloCegarra solucionado mas abajo

Comment: En mi caso el problema era una incompatibilidad entre google_sign_in y otra librería nativa de push notifications que usa firebase, lo arreglé añadiendo el support v4

Comment: ahh yo ya tenia la libreria supportV4 por eso no me dio un error con el plugin de CloudMessaging de Firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hubieron unos cambios en el plugin de Google sign-in. 
La última versión es la de hoy : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in#-changelog-tab-

Por ahora para solucionar el issue, apunta a una versión anterior directamente :

```
google_sign_in: "3.2.2"
```

Luego ejecuta:

```
flutter clean
```

Comment: Tengo esa versión ahora y ya hice el flutter clean pero nada :S me llama la atención ese error en ModernAsyncTask

Comment: la tienes "3.2.2"  o ^3.2.2

Comment: Ahí si me mataste , ahora no tengo la compu pero mañana veo y te confirmo dale ? Gracias Diego !! Siempre dandome una mano !!

Comment: dale no hay problema, para eso estamos, cuando le pones ^3.2.2 , trata de buscar si hubo minor updates, y obtiene la última, en este caso estaría usando 3.2.4 y esa versión trae cambios de dependencias.

Comment: Acabo de verlo y el problema persiste , es solo cuando entro con el plugin de Google_Sign_In porque si entro mediante Firebase Auth no tengo este inconveniente.

Comment: Que version de firebase auth tienes?

Comment: puedes revisar el pubspec.lock y ver que versión de google sign in tiene

Comment: tengo la 0.5.20 , igualmente probé actualizando a la última y sigue igual . El de google quedó en la que me dijiste 3.2.2.

Comment: me parece raro, antes te estuvo funcionando? actualizaste algo más?

Comment: Si , funcionaba sin problemas. Solo actualice flutter en android studio.

Comment: puedes parece que rompieron algo, intenta desintalar el app , borra el  pubspec.lock , ejecuta flutter clean  y finalmente corre la aplicación.

Comment: vos que versión de flutter y dart tenés? para ver si puedo llevar todo a esa versión. El problema sigue estando , pero me sorprende ese error ModernAsyncTask , parece que falla el await en donde se loguea con google.

Comment: probaste lo que te dije? estoy con Flutter v0.10.2 channel dev y  Dart 2.1.0-dev.8.0.flutter-bf26f760b1

Comment: sisi , pero sigue igual , no se si algo de mi instalación rompió el plugin o algo así , veo si reinstalando todo se soluciona.

Comment: Ok, me avisas . Sino trata de crear un proyecto limpio como demo.

Comment: Diego estuve armando un proyecto nuevo y vi que entre tantos cambios habia algunas diferencias en el builgradlew tanto a nivel de proyecto como de app. hice una copia del nuevo , lo pasè a viejo y funcionó correctamente. Igual dejo la respuesta como válida para que se observe la respuesta final.